# animate a UIProgressView's change

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

Is it possible to animate the change of a `UIProgressView` such that the display will move smoothly to the new value?

Kinda like NSProgressIndicator does.

Comment: Did you get any solution?

Answer (score 62, accepted):

If you interested in this please fill a bug report, Duplicate/5883058:

Title: **`UIProgressView setProgress:(float)value animated:(BOOL)animated`**

**Problem Description:** 
`UIProgressView should` have a `setProgress:(float)value animated:(BOOL)animated` function like `UISlider` to be able to animate the progress.

https://bugreport.apple.com

Comment: If you're a registered developer, perhaps now would be a good time to check the change log! :)

Comment: Your voices have been heard, in iOS 5 SDK we now have a method
  `- (void)setProgress:(float)progress animated:(BOOL)animated`.
Well done :).

Comment: @JulianD. Is it possible to change the speed of the animation?

Answer (score 6):

The UIProgressView method `setProgress:animated:` was added in iOS 5:

```
[progressView setProgress:1.0 animated:YES];
```

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIProgressView_Class/index.html

```
- (void)setProgress:(float)progress animated:(BOOL)animated
```

> **animated** - YES if the change should be animated, NO if the change should happen immediately.
>
> Available in iOS 5.0 and later.

Answer (score 3):

**(Swift version)**

The UIProgressView method `setProgress:animated:`:

```
self.progressView.setProgress(1, animated: true)
```

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIProgressView_Class/index.html

```
open func setProgress(_ progress: Float, animated: Bool)
```

> **animated** - **TRUE** if the change should be animated, **FALSE** if the change should happen immediately.